# Change location of Debug Help Flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, debugging-questions

Right now, the flag to close questions because they are asking for debugging help without providing the material / effort expected here is considered an off-topic flag.

In my opinion, it isn't really off-topic but more of a too broad or unclear question since if the question included that information, people could then help answer the question, and aside of the flag reason, the question is probably seeking advice on programming within the guidelines specified in the help center.

Therefore, I suggest that the flag is moved to another location than off-topic as I feel such questions are on-topic; they just need to provide information.

Comment: The problem is that "off-topic" is a misnomer altogether. See [Can we rename the off-topic close reason label on the primary screen?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186024/can-we-rename-the-off-topic-close-reason-label-on-the-primary-screen)

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, good point, that is true; oh well, I'm fine with changing the category all together.